# iOS: Switch view controller behind current modal view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

When I launch my app I'm presented with the root view controller (currently just a picture) which then pops up a modal view controller for the walk through. Once the user finishes the walk through, I want to dismiss the modal view controller and have the user be instantly presented with the main view controller for the app (rather than the root).

My issue is I can't figure out how to go about doing this. Currently all I can do is dismiss the modal back to the root, then switch the root view controller to the main one. This makes for a very ugly transition.

```
//WalkthroughViewController.m
-(void)completeWalkthrough:(UIButton *)sender {
   // What can I do here to switch the RootViewController
   // to display MainViewController ?
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work, (it's late here) but I would possibly look into making the root view controller a delegate of the modal view.

Rather than dismissing the modal as you are doing now, pressing the 'completeWalThrough' button would call a delegate method. You could simultaneously dismiss the modal view and then push the main view controller from root View controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly achieve this with an Unwind Segue as well. In the Unwind Segue method of your Rootviewcontroller, present the Mainviewcontroller without delay.

Comment: I don't think unwind would work, seeing as the main VC is not loaded unless the walk through has been completed, so I have no history to go back to.